# Graph: Coloring.

Tags: graph-theory

We consider the following graph $G$ (see picture below). I have to find

**a)** A matching of maximum size,

**b)** $\alpha(G)$

**c)** $\chi(G)$

**d)** $\chi'(G)$ which is a coloring of the edges.

**My answers**

**a)** I found a perfect matching, and thus a maximum matching so it's fine.

**b)** I don't understand what are the independents sets.

**c)** It's obvious that it's not one or two colorable. I found a $4-$coloration, but I'm not able to prove that it's not $3-$colorable. Any help would be welcome.

**d)** I know that $\Delta (G)\leq \chi'(G)\leq \Delta (G)+1$. I found a $6-$coloration of the edges but I'm not able to prove that it's not $5-$colorable. Any help would be welcome.

[image: On the image below]

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: what do you mean ?

Comment: @idm He quoted a strange line. Did you mean unable?

Comment: For your question c : I would look at the face coloring of the dodecahedron (I let you convince yourself that since this is the dual to the icosahedron, the face coloring of the dodecahedron is equivalent to the vertex coloring of the icosahedron).$\\$ Now, look at the central face of the dodecahedron : it has one color and the surrounding faces cannot be colored in
less than 3 colors, so since you found a 4 coloring, it means the chromatic number is 4 for the icosahedron.

Comment: @Alex: What I want to say is I'n not able to prove it. Is more clear ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the inability to $3$-color the graph, we observe the outside triangle must receive $3$ distinct colors.  This implies the following colors:

[image]

but then e.g. vertex $9$ cannot be colored without introducing a new color.

An independent set is a set of vertices, no two of which are adjacent.  E.g. $\{1,7,9\}$ is an independent set, because no two of $1$, $7$, or $9$ are adjacent.  We can argue that this is the largest by observing that an independent set cannot have two vertices from the same triangle, so any independent set of size $4$ must have one vertex from each of these triangles:

[image]

If it has vertex $10$, then it must have vertex $2$ (otherwise we get a clash), which means it must also have vertex $6$ (otherwise we get a clash), but then we get a clash no matter which vertex in the triangle $\{3,7,8\}$ we add in.

For the edge coloring, we take the one-factor colored orange below:

[image]

and rotate it, which assigns the first three colors.  What's left is two $6$-cycles (dotted), which is $2$-edge-colorable.

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot for your post, that helps me a lot :-). For the independant set, I would say that they are $\{1,10,7,8\}$, $\{2,12,6\}$, $\{3,12,4\}$ and $\{9,5\}$. Then $\alpha(G)=4$ ? (because there is $4$ independent set.) And Bravo for the edges coloring. If I can find a maximum matching, this technique always work ?

Comment: But $\{1,10,7,8\}$ is not an independent set: $7$ and $8$ are adjacent.  And $\alpha(G)$ is the maximum size of an independent set.  I believe it's size $3$, because $\{1,7,8\}$ is an independent set.  Next the task is to eliminate the possibility of an independent set of size $4$, and I propose doing in algorithmically.  (Actually, I just thought of a better way to prove this.)

Comment: And, as for the edge coloring; I just stumbled upon it as I thought it would be more efficient to use the symmetry.  It wouldn't work in most cases, e.g., when there is no symmery.

Comment: Proving that the independence number is $3$ also proves that the graph is not $3$-colorable.

Comment: @Rebecca: of course, sorry for the mistakes of independent set ? What do you thing about $\{1,10,8\}$, $\{2,12,6\}$,$\{3,12,4\}$ and $\{9,5,8\}$ ? But actually $\{1,10,7\}$, $\{2,12,6\}$, $\{3,11,4\}$, $\{9,5\}$, $\{8\}$ is an other list of independent set. So what is $\alpha(G)$ ? The cardinal of the smallest set of independent set ?  If yes, how can I be sure that a collection of independent set I have found is the smallest ? My be we have a result like $\alpha(G)=\chi(G)$ or $\alpha(G)\leq \chi(G)$, don't we ? Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: $\alpha(G)$ is the largest size of an independent set (not the number of independent sets).  So $\{1,7,10\}$ has size $3$, so does $\{2,6,12\}$ and so on.  $3$ is the biggest we can get, so $\alpha(G)=3$ (but we need to check that there are no independent sets of size $4$).  (@bof: oh, I didn't think of that; obviously $\chi(G) \geq |V(G)|/\alpha(G)=12/3=4$.)

Comment: Thanks. And how to prove there is no independent set of size 4 ?